# Strange C++ Class output

Tags: c++, xcode

Below is the output in one of my functions in a Class I'm writing for my C++ programming Lab:

```
400370r307.18192e 22404.03336e-41370390400360
```

**Code** involved:

`class Worker`

```
void Worker::displayWorker()
cout << name;
cout << hour;
cout << total;
```

(I am programming on a Mac with Xcode 4.4.1)
...

Here's the array of workers and the call for displaying the worker-

```
employeeArray[i].displayWorker();
```

Any ideas on what that output means?

Comment: looks like scientific notation to me e and e means multiplied by 10 at the power of (number after e), however the second number after e seems extremely small, are you sure you pasted the actual output?, and I don't get what the r is... what are the types of the variables named name, hour and total?

Comment: `std::cout` won't add whitespace between the printed values, automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some floating point numbers, but the 'r' is "odd" (probably part of the name). Suggest breaking it up a bit better:

```
void Worker::displayWorker()
cout << "name=" << name << endl;
cout << "hour=" << hour << endl;
cout << "total=" << total << endl;
```